# Installation error in tablet android application

Tags: android, google-maps, tablet, failed-installation

Made a android app but not supportable in tablet.It uses `Google APIs [Android 2.2]` and has a lot of map and `GPS` things.It worked well in phones but When I run the app in tablet, it says

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
```

my manifest file has:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
     />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity ..........
```

Also made

```
res/layout
res/layout-land
res/layout-large
```

I think the `<uses-library />` is causing problem.Writing `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="false />` will not solve my case because Google map is necessary whether it is phone or tablet.

Any Suggestions ?
Thanks !

Comment: <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>  only write this. just try

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Right click your project > Properties > Android > Check **Google API** not **Android** with the equivalent api level you are using

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is because the tablet when you want test haven't google maps libraries, some tablets not support maps applications because don't have GPS, and the fabricant not incorporate google maps libraries; is something not functional in the product.